# Conjugation with a unitary is $\sigma$-weakly continuous.

Tags: operator-theory, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M \subseteq B(H)$ be a von Neumann algebra. Let $U: H \to K$ be a unitary  where $K$ is another Hilbert space and consider a faithful $*$-representation
$$\pi: M \hookrightarrow B(K): m \mapsto UmU^*.$$
Is $\pi$ normal (= $\sigma$-weakly continuous = weak$^*$-continuous = ultra-weakly continuous)?

Attempt: It suffices to show that $\pi(M)= UMU^*$ is a von Neumann algebra, since a $*$-isomorphism between von Neumann algebras is automatically normal. There are now several ways to proceed:

- Show that $\pi(M)$ is strongly/weakly closed.
- Show that $\pi(M)'' = \pi(M)$.

However, none of these seem easy to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think things are simpler: First observe that $\mathbb{B}(H)\to\mathbb{B}(K)$, $T\mapsto UTU^*$ is a $*$-isomorphism between von Neumann algebras, thus, as you said, normal. Hence $\pi$, which is merely a restriction of this map is normal.

If you want to verify that $\pi(M)$ is a von Neumann algebra, simply show that $\pi(M)$ is storngly closed: Let $\{x_\lambda\}\subset M$ be a net such that $\pi(x_\lambda)\to y\in\mathbb{B}(K)$ strongly, so we have that $ux_\lambda u^*\to y$. We want to show that $y\in\pi(M)$. Multiplicaton is separately continuous, so
$$u^*\cdot(ux_\lambda u^*)\cdot u\to u^*yu$$
strongly. But $u^*ux_\lambda u^*u=x_\lambda$, so $x_\lambda\to u^*yu$ strongly hence $u^*yu\in M$, since $M$ is strongly closed. But since it is obvious that $y=u(u^*yu)u^*=\pi(u^*yu)$, we have that $y\in\pi(M)$.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. I should stop studying when it's later than 1am... Thanks! Alternatively, the image of a normal $*$-morphism is a von Neumann algebra. This may substitute your second paragraph.

Comment: @user839372 do you maybe have a reference for a proof of this? I'm sorry I have recently started dealing with von Neumann algebras so I'd like to check out the proof.

Comment: I believe it is even in Murphy.

Comment: @user839372 I don't think Murphy talks about normal maps at all from what i remember

Comment: Normal = ultraweakly continuous, right? But I think murphy has this result only for the WO topology. Maybe check out if Lectures on von Neumann algebras by Stratila and Zsado, p73 (some corollary on that page) is what you are looking for?

Comment: @user839372 thanks, i will have a look!

Comment: Let me know once you have taken a look! Maybe I'm misinterpreting something.